# Python Beginner Question about practice problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and need help understanding what I am doing wrong. The task I am trying to accomplish is create a list of integers from 1-100, and then create two other lists based off those numbers and finish by printing both lists. However, I am having trouble with getting the second list to write to a file named target list.txt. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
num1 = input("Please Input a name for the file ending it with .txt. ")
numb_list = open(num1, "w")
mylist = []


def integer_list():
    for numbers in range(1, 101):
        mylist.append(numbers)
        numb_list.write(str(numbers) + "\n")
        print(numbers, end="\n")


integer_list()
print(mylist)
numb_list.close()


def target_list():
    for numbers2 in range(25, 75):
        mylist.append(numbers2)
        target_list.write(numbers2+ "\n")
        print(numbers2, end="\n")


target_list()
print(mylist)
target_list.close()
```

Comment: ```target_list.write(numbers2+ "\n")``` is this line causing the error?, maybe because you are trying to write a string and integer together, convert the integer to string

Comment: Where you have put `target_list.write(numbers2+ "\n")`, what are you expecting that line of code to do? You say "I am having trouble with getting the second list to write to a file named target list.txt". Do you have any kind of reference material for how to write to files? I think you should review it. Alternately: at the top of your program, where you did `numb_list = open(num1, "w")` - in your own words, what is the purpose of this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You didn't open the second file. You used the name of the function `target_list` instead of a new file. This is what's causing your program to fail.
2. Don't use global state in the functions. You can `return` a new list on each call. This prevents the one call of the function from effecting the behavior of the next call.
3. Use function parameters to allow the function to act slightly differently. This makes the function more usable and avoids duplication of code.

```
def integer_list(start, end):
    file_name = input("Please Input a name for the file ending it with .txt. ")
    num_list = []
    num_file = open(file_name, "w")
    for num in range(start, end):
        num_list.append(num)
        num_file.write(str(num) + "\n")
        print(num)
    num_file.close()
    return num_list


num_list1 = integer_list(1, 101)
print(num_list1)

num_list2 = integer_list(25, 75)
print(num_list2)
```

Comment: This made sense to me. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You did not open a second file. `target_list.write` is where you are having an error and the reason is because `target_list` is a function not a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems with [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

Here is the fixed code:

```
num1 = input("Please input a name for the file ending it with .txt ")
numb_list = open(num1, "w")

global mylist
mylist = []


def integer_list():
    for numbers in range(1, 101):
        mylist.append(numbers)
        numb_list.write(str(numbers) + "\n")
        print(numbers)#, end="\n")


integer_list()
print(mylist)
#numb_list.close()


def target_list():
    for numbers in range(25, 75):
        mylist.append(numbers)
        numb_list.write(str(numbers)+"\n") # Needed to be a string
        print(numbers)#, end="\n")


target_list()
print(mylist)
numb_list.close()
```